# Need search result on keyress in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I need to implement my search module in magento such as soon as I start enter keyword in search Box it will show results in same page. 
I think I need to use ajax with keypress event 
I like to implement like below link
https://jadopado.com/en-ae/

Comment: Yeah, you probably do. Or some sort of modern JS data binding. Either way, what is the question? Doesn't seem like an appropriate StackOverflow post.

Comment: specify what you have try for this.